# MongoDB Aggregation is slow on Indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

I have a collection with ~2.5m documents, the collection size is `14,1GB`, storage size `4.2GB` and average object size `5,8KB`. I created two separate indexes on two of the fields `dataSourceName` and `version` (text fields) and tried to make an aggregate query to list their 'grouped by' values.
(Trying to achieve this: `select dsn, v from collection group by dsn, v`).

```
db.getCollection("the-collection").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : "$dataSourceName", 
                    "version" : "$version"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Even though MongoDB eats ~10GB RAM on the server, the fields are indexed and nothing else is running at all, the aggregation takes ~40 seconds.

I tried to make a new index, which contains both fields in order, but still, the query does not seem to use the index:

```
{ 
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                }, 
                "fields" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "_id" : NumberInt(0)
                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "namespace" : "db.the-collection", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : "$dataSourceName", 
                    "version" : "$version"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

I am using MongoDB 3.6.5 64bit on Windows, so it should use the indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

<strike>As @Alex-Blex suggested, I tried it with sorting, but I an get OOM error:</strike>

```
The following error occurred while attempting to execute the aggregate query

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 16819: 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server server-address:port. 

The full response is:
{ 

    "ok" : 0.0, 

    "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", 

    "code" : NumberInt(16819), 

    "codeName" : "Location16819"

}
```

My bad, I tried it on the wrong collection... Adding the same sort as the index works, now it is using the index. Still not fast thought, took ~10 seconds to give me the results.

The new exaplain:

```
{ 
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                }, 
                "sort" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "version" : NumberInt(1)
                }, 
                "fields" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "_id" : NumberInt(0)
                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "namespace" : "....", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
                        "transformBy" : {
                            "dataSourceName" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "version" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "_id" : NumberInt(0)
                        }, 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "dataSourceName" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "version" : NumberInt(1)
                            }, 
                            "indexName" : "dataSourceName_1_version_1", 
                            "isMultiKey" : false, 
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "dataSourceName" : [

                                ], 
                                "version" : [

                                ]
                            }, 
                            "isUnique" : false, 
                            "isSparse" : false, 
                            "isPartial" : false, 
                            "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "direction" : "forward", 
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "dataSourceName" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ], 
                                "version" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : "$dataSourceName", 
                    "version" : "$version"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to says exactly opposite:

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index

Your first stage is `$group`, which is neither `$match` nor `$sort`.

Try to sort it on the first stage to trigger use of the index:

```
db.getCollection("the-collection").aggregate(
    [
        { $sort: { dataSourceName:1, version:1 } },
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "dataSourceName" : "$dataSourceName", 
                    "version" : "$version"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Please note, it should be a single compound index with the same fields and sorting:

```
db.getCollection("the-collection").createIndex({ dataSourceName:1, version:1 })
```

Comment: @appl3r, yes and because of the the sorting hack is advised by aggregation inventor https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16388?focusedCommentId=844821&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-844821 Give it a try.

Comment: yeah, makes sense 100Mb must be to low for your collection. Try to allow disk usage. It still might be quicker than 40 seconds you have with collscan.

Comment: No, I made a mistake and tried it on a wrong collection. Still not really fast though. took 10 seconds :(